# OpenNLP NameFinder Training on C#

Tags: java, c#, .net, opennlp, ikvm

I'd like to train a new model in OpenNLP using C#. I used IKVM for the java part. Here's the method for my train:
(I referenced java.io into jv and referenced open.tools into op)

```
 public string train(string lang, string entity, jv.FileInputStream taggedCorpusStream, jv.FileOutputStream modelStream)
    {
        //for encoding 
        java.nio.charset.Charset charset = java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("UTF-8");

        try
        {
            op.util.ObjectStream lineStream = new op.util.PlainTextByLineStream(taggedCorpusStream, charset);
            op.util.ObjectStream sampleStream = new op.namefind.NameSampleDataStream(lineStream);

            op.namefind.TokenNameFinderModel model;
            jv.OutputStream modelOut = null;

            try
            {
                model = op.namefind.NameFinderME.train(lang, entity, sampleStream, op.util.TrainingParameters.defaultParams(), new op.namefind.TokenNameFinderFactory());

                modelOut = new jv.BufferedOutputStream(modelStream);

                if (model != null)
                {
                    model.serialize(modelOut);
                }

                return entity + " model trained successfully";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                sampleStream.close();
                if (modelOut != null)
                {
                    modelOut.close();
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
        return "Something goes wrong with training module.";           
    }
```

I am getting a NullReference Exception at the part of calling the NameFinder.train in the 5th parameter which is the TokenNameFinderFactor. Now my question is what its primary use for and what alternatives or ways can I use to fix this? Do I need to create my own TokenNameFinderFactor? I don't get or understand the documentation of it [here](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.6.0/apidocs/opennlp-tools/opennlp/tools/namefind/TokenNameFinderFactory.html) on how to implement it. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Its been a while since you posted the Q.. Not sure if you found a solution.  I had a similar problem (more exactly the problem that's described here http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.opennlp.user/937).  The solution was simple.

Copy all the IKVM dlls into your project folder (debug/release).  I had referenced only a few and hence was getting the error.  It is most likely one or two of those dlls that are required for this purpose but I didn't bother to nail down the specific ones.

Now, I am able to train new models.

Regards,
Ram